# How to select all the divs contained within same parent-div except one

Tags: jquery

How do I select all the divs within one parent-div except one? Let's say I have code like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to select `#child1` `#child2`. Of course I could just select them normally, but let's say I have many child-divs.

P.S. I don't want any selector like last or something since it's not said it has to be always the last that I want to skip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**:

```
$('#parent div').not('#child3')
```

or [**:not**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('#parent div:not("#child3")');
```

This will select all your child divs inside parent div except `#child3` element.

Comment: Is there any difference in performance of those two? I mean: is any of those two faster (if yes, which one)?

Comment: You can use [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) to test it. But I think it's most likely the same.

Comment: I've already test it, the `.not()` faster than `:not()` by `6.05%`

Comment: Thanks, no need for that since you have told me that the difference isn't big ;).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#parent > div').not('#child3');
```

or

```
$('#parent > div:lt(2)').
```

or

```
$('#parent > div:not("#child3")');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `not` method.

```
$("#parent > div").not("#child3")
```

this will select all **direct** children of parent div except child3

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not` pseudo-class in CSS...no need for Jquery

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kbF3/)

```
#parent div:not(#child3) {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

Comment: I know, but I need it to be selected in jQuery ;).

Comment: Then don't use CSS as a tag,

Comment: I used it, because as you can see it's also possible to use normal css electors in jQuery code. So actually if I would have only received css way to do it, I could have just made it $('css_code').